# PROCV ATÉ ULTIMA LINHA QUE CONTÉM DADOS (MACRO)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Gostaria de saber como poderia fazer com que a minha tabela que contém as macro com funções de PROCV encontre até a última linha que contém dados e retorne os valores.

```html
Sub Preenche_com_Procv()

' COLUNA A 
    'Selecionar a planilha encerramento
    Sheets("ENCERRAMENTO").Select
    
    'Inserir a função PROCV
    Range("A3").Formula = "=VLOOKUP('DIA 28'!R[-2]C,'DIA 28'!R[-2]C:R[66]C,1,FALSE)"
    
    'Copiar essa fórmula
    Range("A3").Copy
    
    'Colar até o final do intervalo
    Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown).Offset(0)).PasteSpecial
    
    
    
 ' COLUNA B
    
    'Inserir a função PROCV para B1
    Range("B3").Formula = "=VLOOKUP('DIA 29'!R[-2]C[-1],'DIA 29'!R[-2]C[-1]:R[64]C[-1],1,FALSE)"
    
    'Copiar essa fórmula
    Range("B3").Copy
    
    'Colar até o final do intervalo
    Range("B3", Range("B3").End(xlDown).Offset(0)).PasteSpecial
    
    
' COLUNA C
    
       'Inserir a função PROCV para C3
    Range("C3").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],C[-1],1,FALSE),""Não encontrado"")"
    
    'Copiar essa fórmula
    Range("C3").Copy
    
    'Colar até o final do intervalo
    Range("C3", Range("C3").End(xlDown).Offset(0)).PasteSpecial
    
    
End Sub
```

É uma planilha onde tenho minha planilha fixa "ENCERRAMENTO", onde nele importo dois txt com os dados e ele faz o procv dessa planilha (Planilha1) automaticamente quando clico em um botão, porém ele está fazendo PROCV até a última linha da planilha, mesmo sem conter dados o que fica enorme. Como poderia inserir na minha macro essa parte de encontrar linha com dados?

Comment: Vide orientações dadas na primera vez que perguntou: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/552383/70

Comment: já editei, porém ainda continua fechada

Comment: Para evitar duplicação de informações, bloqueei os comentários daqui, duplicações não são permitidas (mas está liberado na postagem original). Queira editar [sua pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/552383/70) linkada no 1o comentário, conforme as instruções dadas lá. Se a comunidade entender que ficou boa a postagem, votam para reabrir. Se não reabrir, provavelmente a edição foi insuficiente. Uma boa lida na documentação passada lá pode ajudar a entender o objetivo do site.